# an array of non-coherent types, that have something in common (array of concepts)

Tags: c++, loops, templates, polymorphism, virtual

I think the use case is frequent, when you have multiple templated classes that have an element (variable or fcn) in common, and you want to call the fcn for all of them in a loop-like way.

Clearly, we can define a base class and make a list of base-class pointers, and use them to loop, but I am trying to avoid pointers (for copy problems) and virtual functions (for optimization reasons)

```cpp
template <typename T> 
struct A {T _value; void foo(){cout<<_value;}};

A<int> a_1{1}; A<float> a_2{2.0f}; ...

void foo_all(){ a_1.foo(); a_2.foo(); ... }

// for (auto i :{a_1,a_2, ...}) is not possible
// array<A<T>,10>; is not also possible, if T is variable
```

Is some sort of design pattern/ idiom known for this use case
Is it planned to have an iteratable container for concepts some when in the future?

Comment: What is the fcn?

Comment: [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)?

Comment: types that satisfy a concept are still different types. A container can only store elements of the same type

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks for the hint,  that was too late reply I belive =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kind of found a solution by implementing my own tuple (without allocation)

```cpp
template <typename T1, typename... Tn> struct tuple
{
    tuple(T1&& first, Tn&&... rest): m_first(first), m_rest(std::forward<Tn>(rest)...){};
    T1 m_first; tuple<Tn...> m_rest;
};

template <typename T> struct tuple<T>  /*specialization*/
{ 
    tuple(T&& first): m_first(first){};
    T m_first; 
};

template<class functor,typename... Tn>
void apply(functor&& fcn, tuple<Tn...>& t) 
{ 
    fcn(t.m_first); 
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Tn)>1) apply(std::forward<functor>(fcn), t.m_rest); 
};
```

and calling

```
apply([](auto& x){x.foo();},tuple{A<int>{1},A<float>{2.0f}});
```

Another solution is having an std::variant and a visitor function

```
using var = std::variant<A<int>,A<float>>;
std::array<var ,2> arr {A<int>{1},A<float>{2.0f}};
std::visit([](auto& x){x.foo();}, arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying [*variadic template*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)?

```cpp
template <typename T, typename... Types>
void callAll(T&& value, Types&&... values) {
    value.foo();
    if constexpr (sizeof...(values) > 0) {
        callAll(values...);
    }
}
```

And then

```cpp
callAll(a_1, a_2);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cKM97deM7)

If you're using C++20, you can use [*concepts*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) to restrict the argument type.

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept IsA = requires(T x)
{
    { x.foo() };
};

template <typename T, typename... Types>
requires IsA<T>
void callAll(T&& value, Types&&... values)
```

Comment: It you are already using C++17 (`if constexpr`), you may as well just use a fold expression instead of recursion: `((void)values.foo(), ...);`.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for addition.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, Doing it this way is clever definitely, and more readable, but I am quite more interested in a more generic way, to do that for example when I have 5 foo() functions , and also more in the direction of having a container, so that when an a_3 is added, I don‘t have to go through all fcn calls and adjust the parameters one-by-one.

Comment: @AhmedSabek Ummmm, I don't think there is a good way. If you remove the restriction of using pointers, you can combine CRTP and static polymorphism.